# Upload bot, using MySQL excessively

Tags: performance, php, mysql, comparative-review

I have a PHP bot running on a shared host. My account often get suspended. When I asked to web hosting service, they said that my account suspended because of excessive MySQL usage.

There is an upload.php and db_functions.php files. Upload PHP runs every half hour. I open and close MySQL connections in every function.

Is building a MySQL connection at the beginning of the upload.php and closing at the end of the upload.php able to prevent excessive usage?

Which one is effective between these two situation?

**1st situation**

upload.php

```
require_once(WEBSITE_ROOT.'/'.APP_DIRECTORY.'/functions/db_fns.php');

$subreddits = subreddit_getir($db_user[category]);
$posts = grab_reddit_picture($subreddits);

foreach($posts as $post){
        $hashtags = make_hashtag($db_user[category], $post[subreddit]); //#city #culture etc.

        if($post[type]=='resim'){
            $rawImage = file_get_contents($post[url]);
            if(!$rawImage){break;}
            $basename = preg_replace('/^.+[\\\\\\/]/', '', $post[url]);

            if(!is_picture_inserted($db_user[tw_id], $post[url])){
                $pic_id = insert_picture($db_user[tw_id], $post[title], $post[url], $post[type]);

                file_put_contents(WEBSITE_ROOT.'/'.APP_DIRECTORY.'/images/'.$basename, $rawImage);

                //image_text($basename, $db_user[tw_name]);

                // assign access token on each page load
                $cb->setToken($db_user['oauth_token'], $db_user['oauth_token_secret']);

                $reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia(array(
                    'status'  => substr(convert_hashtag($post[title]), 0, 72).' '.$hashtags.' ',
                    'media[]' => WEBSITE_ROOT.'/'.APP_DIRECTORY.'/images/'.$basename
                ));
                print_r($reply);
                //break;
            }
        }else{
            if(!is_picture_inserted($db_user[tw_id], $post[url])){
                insert_picture($db_user[tw_id], $post[title], $post[url], $post[type]);
                $cb->setToken($db_user['oauth_token'], $db_user['oauth_token_secret']);

                $reply = $cb->statuses_update(array(
                    'status'  => substr(convert_hashtag($post[title]), 0, 100).' '.$post['url'].' '.$hashtags
                ));
                print_r($reply);        
            }
        }
}
```

db_functions.php

```
<?php
    function db_connect() {
        $connection = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

        if (!$connection)
        {
          echo 'No connection!';
          mysql_error(); 
        }

        if (!$connection->select_db(DATABASE))
        {
          echo 'No database!'; 
          mysql_error();
        }

        $connection->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
        return $connection;    
    }

    function db_result_to_array($result) 
    {
        $res_array = array();

        for ($count = 0; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $count++)
        {
            $res_array[$count] = $row;    
        }
        return $res_array;
    }


    function is_user_created($id, $tablo_adi)
    {
        $conn = db_connect();

        $query = "SELECT id FROM ".$tablo_adi." WHERE tw_id = ".$id;

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        $result = $result->fetch_array();

        if($result)
        {
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(mysqli_ping($conn))
        {
            $conn->close(); 
        }
    }

    function create_user($user_id, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret){
        $conn = db_connect();


            $query = sprintf("INSERT into reddit_twitter SET 
                tw_id = %s,
                oauth_token = '%s',
                oauth_token_secret = '%s'",
                $user_id,
                $oauth_token,
                $oauth_token_secret);
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if(!$result){
            echo 'Dünyayı ele geçirmeye falan mı çalışıyorsun?';
            echo $conn->error;
        }else{
            return $conn->insert_id;
        }
        $conn->close();
    }

    function select_users(){
        $conn = db_connect();

        $query = "SELECT * FROM reddit_twitter ORDER by id DESC";

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        $result = db_result_to_array($result);

        return $result;
        $conn->close();
    }

    function insert_picture($tw_id, $title, $picture, $type){
        $conn = db_connect();

        $query = sprintf("INSERT into pics SET 
            tw_id = '%s',
            title = '%s',
            picture = '%s',
            type = '%s'
            ",
            $tw_id,
            $conn->real_escape_string($title),
            $picture,
            $type
            );

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if(!$result){
            echo 'Dünyayı ele geçirmeye falan mı çalışıyorsun?';
            echo $conn->error;
        }else{
            return $conn->insert_id;
        }
        $conn->close();
    }


    function is_picture_inserted($uid, $basename)
    {
        $conn = db_connect();

        $query = "SELECT id FROM pics WHERE tw_id = ".$uid." AND picture = '".$basename."'";

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if($result)
        {
            return $result[id];
        }
        else
        {
            echo $conn->error;
            return false;
        }

        if(mysqli_ping($conn))
        {
            $conn->close(); 
        }
    }
?>
```

---

**2nd situation**

upload.php

```
require_once(WEBSITE_ROOT.'/'.APP_DIRECTORY.'/functions/db_fns.php');
$conn = db_connect();

$subreddits = subreddit_getir($db_user[category]);
$posts = grab_reddit_picture($subreddits);

foreach($posts as $post){
        $hashtags = make_hashtag($db_user[category], $post[subreddit]); //#city #culture etc.

        if($post[type]=='resim'){
            $rawImage = file_get_contents($post[url]);
            if(!$rawImage){break;}
            $basename = preg_replace('/^.+[\\\\\\/]/', '', $post[url]);

            if(!is_picture_inserted($db_user[tw_id], $post[url])){
                $pic_id = insert_picture($db_user[tw_id], $post[title], $post[url], $post[type]);

                file_put_contents(WEBSITE_ROOT.'/'.APP_DIRECTORY.'/images/'.$basename, $rawImage);

                //image_text($basename, $db_user[tw_name]);

                // assign access token on each page load
                $cb->setToken($db_user['oauth_token'], $db_user['oauth_token_secret']);

                $reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia(array(
                    'status'  => substr(convert_hashtag($post[title]), 0, 72).' '.$hashtags.' ',
                    'media[]' => WEBSITE_ROOT.'/'.APP_DIRECTORY.'/images/'.$basename
                ));
                print_r($reply);
                //break;
            }
        }else{
            if(!is_picture_inserted($db_user[tw_id], $post[url])){
                insert_picture($db_user[tw_id], $post[title], $post[url], $post[type]);
                $cb->setToken($db_user['oauth_token'], $db_user['oauth_token_secret']);

                $reply = $cb->statuses_update(array(
                    'status'  => substr(convert_hashtag($post[title]), 0, 100).' '.$post['url'].' '.$hashtags
                ));
                print_r($reply);        
            }
        }
}
$conn->close();
```

db_functions.php

```
<?php
    function db_connect() {
        $connection = new mysqli(MYSQL_HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);

        if (!$connection)
        {
          echo 'No connection!';
          mysql_error(); 
        }

        if (!$connection->select_db(DATABASE))
        {
          echo 'No database!'; 
          mysql_error();
        }

        $connection->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
        return $connection;    
    }

    function db_result_to_array($result) 
    {
        $res_array = array();

        for ($count = 0; $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); $count++)
        {
            $res_array[$count] = $row;    
        }
        return $res_array;
    }


    function is_user_created($id, $tablo_adi)
    {

        $query = "SELECT id FROM ".$tablo_adi." WHERE tw_id = ".$id;

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        $result = $result->fetch_array();

        if($result)
        {
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }

    function create_user($user_id, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret){


            $query = sprintf("INSERT into reddit_twitter SET 
                tw_id = %s,
                oauth_token = '%s',
                oauth_token_secret = '%s'",
                $user_id,
                $oauth_token,
                $oauth_token_secret);
        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if(!$result){
            echo 'Dünyayı ele geçirmeye falan mı çalışıyorsun?';
            echo $conn->error;
        }else{
            return $conn->insert_id;
        }
    }

    function select_users(){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM reddit_twitter ORDER by id DESC";

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        $result = db_result_to_array($result);

        return $result;
    }

    function insert_picture($tw_id, $title, $picture, $type){

        $query = sprintf("INSERT into pics SET 
            tw_id = '%s',
            title = '%s',
            picture = '%s',
            type = '%s'
            ",
            $tw_id,
            $conn->real_escape_string($title),
            $picture,
            $type
            );

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        if(!$result){
            echo 'Dünyayı ele geçirmeye falan mı çalışıyorsun?';
            echo $conn->error;
        }else{
            return $conn->insert_id;
        }
    }


    function is_picture_inserted($uid, $basename)
    {

        $query = "SELECT id FROM pics WHERE tw_id = ".$uid." AND picture = '".$basename."'";

        $result = $conn->query($query);

        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if($result)
        {
            return $result[id];
        }
        else
        {
            echo $conn->error;
            return false;
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: "Excess usage" is a very vague term. Certainly not spawning connections for every query would be preferred, but we have no way to know what you application is doing as a whole that might be contributing towards "excess usage". I am dubious that your code even works (at least as shown).  For example, what is story with array key names like `$db_user[category]`?  Do you really have a `category` constant defined? If `$db_user` is an associative array with a `category` key, then the references would need to be like `$db_user['category']` (a string value for key not a constant).

Answer (score 1):

You should analyze queries your application do.

**At first glance** it seems that you may have problem with checks:

if (!is_picture_inserted ...)

If you check hundreds or thousands of images then you generate the same (BIG) number of queries.

In such case, I would recommend getting all inserted images by one query and then compare arrays (of inserted images and of received images).

**Another thing to check** is that you have index for tw_id column.